# Improving client latency for receiving multiple data blocks parallely from the server using buffer using Python

Tags: python, tcp, parallel-processing, client-server, buffer

In order to increase the latency of my client, which is receiving data blocks from a server (in my case a software whose sampling rate in 100Hz) I plan to use a buffer. Since my client is not only receiving the data blocks but processing it and giving a real time value (almost) of the result.

Currently, my client code takes 0.1s to receive and process the data blocks.
With the buffer in the client side, I intend to continuously receive the data blocks and in parallel read out the latest data block to process it. This way I make sure that I am processing every data block that the software is sending.

Could someone tell me how to implement a FIFO and in parallel compute in the client side? And if there is a better approach than doing this?

Thank you in advance!

The following is my client code:

```
import socket
import turtle
import timeit
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width = 150, height = 50)
canvas.grid(row = 4, column = 3)
input_label = Label(root, text = "Input all the gratings set straight wavelength values in nm")
input_label.grid(row = 0)

light_label = Label(root, text = 'Status')
light_label.grid(row = 3, column = 3)

# Green light
green_light = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)
green_light.shape('circle')
green_light.color('grey')
green_light.penup()
green_light.goto(0,0)

# Red light
red_light = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)
red_light.shape('circle')
red_light.color('grey')
red_light.penup()
red_light.goto(40,0)




core_string = "Core "
entries = []

label_col_inc = 0
entry_col_inc = 1
core_range = range(1, 5)

for y in core_range:
    core_text = core_string + str(y) + '_' + '25'
    core_label = Label(root, text = core_text)
    entry = Entry(root)
    core_label.grid(row=1, column=label_col_inc, sticky=E)
    entry.grid(row=1, column=entry_col_inc)
    entries.append(entry)
    label_col_inc += 2
    entry_col_inc += 2

threshold_label = Label(root, text = "Threshold in nm")
entry_threshold = Entry(root)

threshold_label.grid(row = 2, sticky = E)
entry_threshold.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

#dataNo_label = Label(root, text = "Number of data to be collected")
#entry_datNo = Entry(root)

#dataNo_label.grid(row = 3, sticky = E)
#entry_datNo.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

# function to receive TCP data blocks
def getData():
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 5000
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((host, port))

    len_message = s.recv(4)
# input of the number of data to be received
    #dataNo = float(entry_datNo.get())

    while len_message:
        #bytes_length = int.from_bytes(len_message,'big') # for the software
        bytes_length = int(len_message.decode('utf-8')) # for the self-made server
        data = s.recv(bytes_length)
        stringdata = data.decode('utf-8')
        rep_str = stringdata.replace(",", ".")
        splitstr = rep_str.split()

        # received wavelength values
        inc = 34
        wav_threshold = []
        for y in entries:
            straight_wav = float(y.get())
            wav = float(splitstr[inc])
            wav_diff = wav - straight_wav
            if wav_diff < 0:
                wav_diff = wav_diff * (-1)
            wav_threshold.append(wav_diff)
            inc += 56

        threshold = float(entry_threshold.get())

        # writing into the file
        data = []
        inc1 = 0
        col1 = 2
        col2 = 6

        data.insert(0, (str(splitstr[0])))
        data.insert(1, (str(splitstr[1])))

        for x in wav_threshold:
            if (x > threshold):
                red_light.color('red')
                green_light.color('grey')
                data.insert(col1, (str(splitstr[34 + inc1])))
                data.insert(col2,(str(x)))
            else:
                red_light.color('grey')
                green_light.color('green')
                data.insert(col1,'-')
                data.insert(col2,'-')
            inc1 += 56
            col1 += 1
            col2 += 1

        write_file(data)
        len_message = s.recv(4)

    else:
        print('out of loop')
        stop = timeit.default_timer()
        print('Time: ', stop - start)
    s.close()

# function to write into the file
def write_file(data):
    with open("Output.txt", "a") as text_file:
        text_file.write('\t'.join(data[0:]))
        text_file.write('\n')


data_button = Button(root, text = "Get data above threshold", command = getData)
data_button.grid(row = 5, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what GUI has to do with your problem ? BTW: GUI usually doesn't like threads and widgets rather have to be used in main thread - and it can make problem. And GUI in  multiprocessing will be even bigger problem - you will need queue to send information from other processes to main processes to display it.

Comment: @furas What kind of problem do you mean? And are you saying GUI with multiprocessing should be avoided? What alternative can I use then?